# How to detect if video is playing in the foreground?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I am trying to detect whether audio I playing or not *or* if video (any video played using any video player application) is playing in the foreground or not, based on which I want to perform some action if it is playing.

I tried to check on the music stream, whether it is active or not (since audio music stream will be active, when video is active), using the following code :

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

if(audioManager.isMusicActive())
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

This works for all audio players and some video players like VLC, or Google Photos, but not with Samsung Video player.

So, I wanted to know if there is a universal way to check if **video** is currently active (that is, playing). Any solutions with code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I rather doubt that this is possible, and if it is, that would be worrisome to me.

Comment: @CommonsWare Isn't there some way to detect if video is playing in the foreground, irrespective of which video player is used, since it is possible for audio under the same conditions?

Comment: Well, video does not imply audio. Dashcam footage, for example, might be video-only. Moreover, while audio can be played in the background and therefore gets exposed via system services, video is a purely foreground thing. The app and the system should know if video is being played, but I would be surprised and disturbed if other apps could figure that out. Moreover, your algorithm for your question would fail for plenty of non-video things, as the method is `isMusicActive()`, not `isVideoPlaying()`, so `isMusicActive()` will return `true` for other audio apps.

Comment: Yes well I want it this to work for both audio and video cases, I will edit my question to imply that